# Golang Regular expression to separate a formula

Tags: go, qregularexpression

Need to split something like 1-(a+b-b-d)*100 into 1, a+b-b-d, 100

I tried `(\+|-|\*|\/)` which will split the string into 1 (a b b d) 100

Answer (score 1):

regular expression pattern:

```bash
^(\d+?)\-(\(.+?\))\*(\d+?)$
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/2rLH8bB1DTi)

```golang
package main

import (
    "log"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(`^(\d+?)\-(\(.+?\))\*(\d+?)$`)
    str := `1-(a+b-b-d)*100`
    // see: https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.FindAllSubmatch
    ret := reg.FindAllSubmatch([]byte(str), -1)

    log.Printf("%s %s %s", ret[0][1], ret[0][2], ret[0][3])
}
```